# Firebase Phone auth opening browser

Tags: android, firebase

I added Sha-1 and Sha -256  fingerprint and also added the following dependencies

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'

And also enabled Android Device Verification API in the cloud console.

still it opening browser when using firebase phone auth- Please help

Answer (score 1):

After spending a half-day found the solution.

After enabling all those options go to firebase where the project is located.
click on  Project setting
Project settings -> App check-> click on the app-> enable safetynet.[image: add sha key and click on save]

Comment: This won't work now. This option is deprecated. is there another solution for this?